# how to print all phone numbers in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code only prints the first phone number. How do I print all of the phone numbers in the file.

```
import re


def findn(filename):
    phonenum= re.compile(r'05\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            phone_number = re.search(phonenum, line)
            if phone_number:

                print("phone number found: "+phone_number.group())
            else:
                print('none')
        print('done')


findn("1.txt")
```

Comment: What does the file look like? Are there multiple phone numbers per line?

Comment: just do the homework

Comment: Break the problem down into little steps, then research those; the internet has most of the answers.  Keep trying, keep digging.  You’ll get it.  Aside, the regex can be more concisely expressed as: `05\d{8}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print a file line by line you can just use a 2 line for loop

```
file = open("name_of_file.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    print(line)
```

You can then save that line to a variable to use later in the loop -

```
file = open("name_of_file.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    phonenb = line
```

Alternatively you could make each line an element in a list -

```
file = "name_of_file.txt"
lines = [line.split() for line in open(file)]
print(lines)
```

Comment: ok that worked for me but the issue here is that if i have 2 or more phone numbers in the same line it will only print the first phone number. how can i solve that ??

Comment: @kkhh you can split each line into a list and then split each list into each individual number with the `spit()` function on each list. Then print each element using there index in a for loop.

Comment: `split()` not `spit()`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `re.search()` with `re.findall()` will probably work(can't test due to the fact I don't have a 1.txt). This is because `re.search()` finds only the instance of a match, while `re.findall()` finds all instances.

```
import re

def findn(filename):
    phonenum= re.compile(r'05\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            phone_number = re.findall(phonenum, line)
            if phone_number:
                print("phone number found: "+phone_number.group())
            else:
                print('none')
        print('done')


findn("1.txt")
```

Comment: i tried it and i have this error:  " print("phone number found: "+phone_number.group())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group' "

Comment: Really? What error?

Comment: print("phone number found: "+phone_number.group())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'